# How to add multiple inputs to an object for rendering in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

New to React and can manage rendering single input values, but I'm trying to render the value of multiple inputs in a list form and can't get my head around it.

I'm trying to add the inputs into an object, and push the object into an array (this is the main issue i'm having), and then render the items in the array. I've used jobs as an example showing what I've managed so far... Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: {
        name: '',
        description: ''
      },
      jobs: []
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      post.name: e.target.value,
      post.name: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

// This is where i've trying to push the inputs into an object...

    this.setState({
      post.name: '',
      post.description: '',
      jobs: this.state.items.concat(this.state.post)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const listItems = this.state.jobs.map((data, key) =>
    <li key={key}>{data}</li>
  )
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <form>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" value={this.state.post.name} placeholder="post name" />
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" value={this.state.post.description} placeholder="post description" />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to render each field of an element in the `jobs` array separately because React can't render objects.

`{ post.name: '', post.description: ''}` is invalid JavaScript syntax. You must set `post` to a new object instead.

You can also use the `name` of the input to choose what field in the `post` object to update, so that you can share the same `onChange` handler for both inputs.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    post: {
      name: "",
      description: ""
    },
    jobs: []
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      post: { ...prevState.post, [name]: value }
    }));
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      jobs: [...prevState.jobs, prevState.post],
      post: { name: "", description: "" }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <form>
          <input
            name="name"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post.name}
            placeholder="post name"
          />
          <input
            name="description"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post.description}
            placeholder="post description"
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {this.state.jobs.map((job, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {job.name}: {job.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```